# List Comprehension is transposing Dataframe

Tags: pandas, filtering, list-comprehension

I am trying to import a .csv of EMG data as a Dataframe and filter each column of data using a list comprehension. Below is a dummy dataframe.

```
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt
test_array = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,2,size=(1000,6)),columns = ['time','RF','VM','TA','GM','BF'])
b,a = butter(4,[0.05,0.9],'bandpass',analog=False)
columns = ['RF','VM','TA','GM','BF']
filtered_df = pd.DataFrame([filtfilt(b,a,test_array.loc[:,i] for i in test_array[columns]])
```

The code above gives a version of the expected output, but instead of returning filtered_df as a (1000,5) dataframe, it is returning a (5,1000) dataframe.

I've tried using df.transpose() on the back end to fix the orientation, but it seems like there should be a more straightforward solution to preventing the transposing in the first place. Is there a way to get the desired output?

Comment: What are `butter` and `filtfilt`?

Comment: sorry - these are functions from scipy. signal to calculate Butterworth coefficients and apply them to a signal. I updated the original chunk to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to how you building the new dataframe.  Just passing in a list from:

```
[filtfilt(b,a,test_array.loc[:,i]) for i in test_array[columns]]
```

pandas will read that in as a dataframe with four rows and column names representing the indices of the numpy array.  If you build your dataframe using a dictionary mapped to each column name like:

```py
results = [filtfilt(b,a,test_array.loc[:,i]) for i in test_array[columns]]
filtered_df = pd.DataFrame(data = dict(zip(columns, results)))
```

you get your desired result

```
           RF        VM        TA        GM        BF
0   -0.072520  0.025846  0.111571  0.043277  0.024290
1   -2.674829  3.139997  0.285869 -0.162487  3.759851
2   -0.521439  3.481993  0.427854 -1.411966  5.422871
3   -2.719175  5.162347  2.195120 -0.535819 -1.721818
4    0.451544  1.730292  0.930652 -2.017700 -0.926594
..        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
995 -5.240183 -0.625118  2.176452  2.065998  1.561615
996 -3.084039 -0.017626 -0.377022 -1.996366  2.041706
997 -5.122489  1.476979 -3.219335  1.609466 -3.707151
998 -2.072177 -0.870773  0.546386  0.031297  0.247766
999  0.141538 -0.048204 -0.601213  0.499631  0.246530

[1000 rows x 5 columns]
```